# Different Display between localhost and network access

Tags: html, css

I have developed a bootstrap web portal which is perfectly fine when viewed from my pc using Wampserver localhost.

However when I access the web through the office network, the view changed.  It seems like every element that should be spanned horizontally have spanned vertically. And some CSS missing, and the logo picture is gone.

I have tried changed to Xamp with latest Apache 2.4.28 but same result.
OS are windows 10 and Windows 7.  Browser is Firefox.

Comment: Check the path of files you are missing currently

Comment: Would that still be the case even if i can view them perfectly fine from Firefox in localhost?

Comment: Check browser console for errors

Comment: It is impossible for us to know whats happening without seeing an example - we're not mind readers! Please provide more information on exactly what is happening and the differences, and what steps you have taken to debug this so we can offer practical help instead of guesses. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for the great response. Well i tried to upload a snapshot but it seems i'm still not allowed to upload a picture.

Comment: Firstly, the web is created in a laptop and tested using wamp server, browser firefox. And when i install the wampserver on my friend pc, and copy the file into his pc, he can view the web file as good as well. For hosting purposes, i install the wamp server into one common unused pc in my office and use that platform for accessing the web thru' network. Here the problem occur, the menu that should be span horizontal goes vertical, seems like the <div> only span one column. And the top menu should have some black borders described in external css but missing.

Comment: To simplify the coding, i use separate header file to copy for each page and use include() to put them together. I tried to remove that and put the header  in main program. Not work. Then someone said it might caused by Apache setting, so i switch to latest apache and tried Xamp. For a note as well, the loading is terribly slow.

Comment: I have tried to install firefox web developer tool to analyze the css. But it seems the tool can only work for external web access.

Comment: I'd wager that it is a relative / absolute path problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue is nor with Xamp or Apache and neither with OS. All you need to use `@media` media-query to target the device width and then write some conditional css which should apply on different width/resolution screens.

Here is the best way to target all devices

```
@media (min-width:320px)  { /* smartphones, portrait iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones (Android) */ }
@media (min-width:480px)  { /* smartphones, Android phones, landscape iPhone */ }
@media (min-width:600px)  { /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, e-readers (Nook/Kindle), landscape 800x480 phones (Android) */ }
@media (min-width:801px)  { /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1025px) { /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1281px) { /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ }
```

Comment: I've just change the port to 8080, just avoid conflict, then decided to change back to port 80, suddenly everything now in place. Webpage view has been corrected. Not really understand why though....